# c# lambda functions and runtime type conversion

Tags: c#

i am creating the following function (psudo code) and would like to know if there is a more efficient way of writing this.

the data is being read from a file and the data types are provided by the user as configuration.

```cs
Func<object,object,object> GetFunction(string op, string dataType) {
    if (op == "sum") {
        if (dataType == 'int') return (a,b) => (int)a + (int) b;
        if (dataType == 'double') return (a,b) => (double)a + (double)b;
        // ... other numeric data types
    }
    elseif (op == "max") {
        if (dataType == 'int') return (a,b) => Math.Max((int)a + (int) b);
        if (dataType == 'double') return (a,b) => Math.Max((double)a + (double)b);

    }
    elseif (op == "min") {
    // ...
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
i tried to implement it like this but the compiler gives the error "error CS0118: 'dataType' is a variable but is used like a type"  when i try to do this.

```cs
Func<object,object,object> GetFunction(string op, Type dataType) {
    if (op == "sum")  return (a,b) => (dataType)a + (dataType) b;
    if (op == "max")  return (a,b) => Math.Max((dataType)a + (dataType) b);
    if (op == "min")  ...
}
```

Comment: Using object as argument types for your func delegates is a bad idea (normally). How are you going to use such delegates meaningfully in your code without doing a casting bonanza...?

Comment: What does more efficient mean? Do you want less code, faster code, readable code? What are you trying to optimize?

Comment: @Chris, no need. See the return statements...

Comment: In this case more efficient means shorter code that avoids the repetition.

Comment: @Chris What version of C# has `elseif` keyword?

Comment: Do you have to pass in the datatypes as strings and not `Type` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that you will have to repeat code, as a generic solution is not possible when arithmetic operators are involved. But by using switch-statements you get a cleaner code than with if-statements

```
object typedObject = Activator.CreateInstance(dataType);
switch (typedObject) {
    case int i:
        switch (op) {
            case "sum":
                return (a, b) => (int)a + (int)b;
            case "max":
                return (a, b) => Math.Max((int)a , (int)b);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    case double d:
        switch (op) {
            case "sum":
                return (a, b) => (double)a + (double)b;
            case "max":
                return (a, b) => Math.Max((double)a, (double)b);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    default:
        return null;
}
```

The trick is to create a dummy object from your `Type` variable and to use it for pattern matching in the outer switch.

---

Since C# 8.0 you can also use switch expressions combined with tuple patterns:

```cs
return (typedObject, op) switch {
    (int, "sum") => (a, b) => (int)a + (int)b,
    (int, "max") => (a, b) => Math.Max((int)a, (int)b),
    (double, "sum") => (a, b) => (double)a + (double)b,
    (double, "max") => (a, b) => Math.Max((double)a, (double)b),
    _ => null
};
```

(7 code lines instead of 22!)

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the few places where you quickly run into a casting nightmare with C#, since it is not possible to use generics here (can't use the arithmetic operators on "T" type). In my opinion the nicest solution is the use of the `generic` type in this case. It may not be very fast, but it gets the shortest source code.

In this case, you should maybe try something like:

```
    public delegate T OperationDelegate<T>(dynamic a, dynamic b);

    public OperationDelegate<T> GetFunction<T>(string op)
    {
        if (op == "sum")
        {
            return (a, b) => a + b;

        }
        else
        if(op == "max") {
            return (a, b) => Math.Max(a, b);

        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

// Use as: 
var myOp = GetFunction<double>("sum");
double result = myOp(1.0, 2.0);
```

You can probably even get rid of the type argument to the GetFunction call somehow.

Answer (score 1):

All thinkings are to avoid `if...else` and `switch...case`.

1. For parameter type, we could use `interface` to avoid `if...else`.
2. For `action` name, I am using `switch...case`, not perfect good.

Someone else could continue on my idea and edit this answer:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //c# will automatically pick best match by give parameter.
        Console.WriteLine("1 + 2 = " + Numeric.Instance.Calculate("Sum", 1, 2));
        Console.WriteLine("Max(1, 2) = " + Numeric.Instance.Calculate("Max", 1.5, 2.1));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    interface INumeric<T>
    {
        T Sum(T a, T b);
        T Max(T a, T b);
        T Min(T a, T b);


        ///// <summary>
        ///// This works only in .NET core 3.0, c# 8.0.
        ///// </summary>
        ///// <param name="method"></param>
        ///// <param name="a"></param>
        ///// <param name="b"></param>
        ///// <returns></returns>
        //public virtual T Calculate(string method, T a, T b)
        //{
        //    switch (method)
        //    {
        //        case "Sum":
        //            {
        //                return Sum(a, b);
        //            }
        //        case "Max":
        //            {
        //                return Max(a, b);
        //            }
        //        case "Min":
        //            {
        //                return Min(a, b);
        //            }
        //        default:
        //            {
        //                throw new NotImplementedException($"Method '{method}' is not supported.");
        //            }
        //    }
        //}
    }

    struct Numeric :
        INumeric<int>,
        INumeric<double>,
        INumeric<long>
    {
        public double Sum(double a, double b) => a + b;

        public double Max(double a, double b) => Math.Max(a, b);

        public double Min(double a, double b) => Math.Min(a, b);

        public int Sum(int a, int b) => a + b;

        public int Max(int a, int b) => Math.Max(a, b);

        public int Min(int a, int b) => Math.Min(a, b);

        public long Sum(long a, long b) => a + b;

        public long Max(long a, long b) => Math.Max(a, b);

        public long Min(long a, long b) => Math.Min(a, b);

        public int Calculate(string method, int a, int b)
        {
            switch (method)
            {
                case "Sum":
                    {
                        return Sum(a, b);
                    }
                case "Max":
                    {
                        return Max(a, b);
                    }
                case "Min":
                    {
                        return Min(a, b);
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        throw new NotImplementedException($"Method '{method}' is not supported.");
                    }
            }
        }

        public double Calculate(string method, double a, double b)
        {
            switch (method)
            {
                case "Sum":
                    {
                        return Sum(a, b);
                    }
                case "Max":
                    {
                        return Max(a, b);
                    }
                case "Min":
                    {
                        return Min(a, b);
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        throw new NotImplementedException($"Method '{method}' is not supported.");
                    }
            }
        }

        public long Calculate(string method, long a, long b)
        {
            switch (method)
            {
                case "Sum":
                    {
                        return Sum(a, b);
                    }
                case "Max":
                    {
                        return Max(a, b);
                    }
                case "Min":
                    {
                        return Min(a, b);
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        throw new NotImplementedException($"Method '{method}' is not supported.");
                    }
            }
        }

        public static Numeric Instance = new Numeric();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic constraint for value types can be tricky, `ValueType` is not allowed as a constraint and is not that useful, since, for example, `Point` is also a `ValueType` and you don't want or need a specific type.
So, I propose you this demented method. Not for public use.

The type of operations that can be performed is defined by an enumerator, so you cannot mispell the operation to perform and it's easy to expand, if needed, without breaking anything.

The accepted value types are limited by the result of a local function, which holds the supported types.

For example, to have the `Max` method return a comparison between an `int` and a `double`, returning the result as a `int`, you can call it like this:

```
int max = GetFunction<int, double, int>(OperationType.Max)(100, 120.5d);
// max = 120
```

or, get the function, then add the parameters when needed:

```
var operationMultiply = GetFunction<int, double, int>(OperationType.Multiply);
var result = operationMultiply(100, 120.5d);
// result = 12050
```

```
Func<T1, T2, TR> GetFunction<T1, T2, TR>(OperationType op) 
    where T1: struct where T2: struct where TR: struct
{
    if (!IsSupported(typeof(T1), typeof(T2))) {
        throw new NotSupportedException($"Operation on {typeof(T1)} and {typeof(T2)} is not supported.");
    }

    switch (op)
    {
        default:
        case OperationType.Sum:
                return (a, b) => (TR)((dynamic)a + b);
        case OperationType.Subtract:
            return (a, b) => (TR)((dynamic)a - b);
        case OperationType.Multiply:
            return (a, b) => (TR)((dynamic)a * (dynamic)b);
        case OperationType.Max:
            return (a, b) => (TR)Math.Max((dynamic)a, (dynamic)b);
    }
    bool IsSupported(Type t1, Type t2)
    {
        Type[] suppTypes = new[] { typeof(int), typeof(decimal), typeof(double), typeof(float) };
        if (!suppTypes.Contains(typeof(T1))) return false;
        if (!suppTypes.Contains(typeof(T2))) return false;
        return true;
    }
}

public enum OperationType
{
    Sum = 0, 
    Subtract,
    Multiply,
    Divide,
    Min, 
    Max,
    //Other supported operations
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some preset `Dictionary` variables to map the strings to `Type`s and operators and then build `Expression`s manually, and compile them:

```
static Dictionary<string, Type> TypeMap = new Dictionary<string, Type> {
    { "int", typeof(Int32) },
    { "double", typeof(double) }
};
static Dictionary<string, (ExpressionType opType, Type methodType, string methodName)> OpMap = new Dictionary<string, (ExpressionType, Type, string)> {
    { "sum", (ExpressionType.Add, null, "") },
    { "difference", (ExpressionType.Subtract, null, "") },
    { "multiply", (ExpressionType.Multiply, null, "") },
    { "max", (ExpressionType.Call, typeof(Math), "Max") },
    { "min", (ExpressionType.Call, typeof(Math), "Min") },
};

Func<object, object, object> MakeFunction(string op, string dataType) {
    var parmType = TypeMap[dataType];
    var parma = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "a");
    var parmb = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "b");
    var changeTypeMI = typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ChangeType", new[] { typeof(object), typeof(Type) });
    var exprParmType = Expression.Constant(parmType);
    var lefta = Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(changeTypeMI, parma, exprParmType), parmType);
    var rightb = Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(changeTypeMI, parmb, exprParmType), parmType);
    Expression expr = null;
    var opTuple = OpMap[op];
    switch (opTuple.opType) {
        case ExpressionType.Call:
            var mi = opTuple.methodType.GetMethod(opTuple.methodName, new[] { parmType, parmType });
            expr = Expression.Call(mi, lefta, rightb);
            break;
        default:
            expr = Expression.MakeBinary(opTuple.opType, lefta, rightb);
            break;
    }
    var body = Expression.Convert(expr, typeof(object));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object, object>>(body, parma, parmb).Compile();
}
```

Note: I added a call to `Convert.ChangeType` to handle if you passed in e.g. an int to a function you made for "double". You could remove it and just leave in the `Expression.Convert` cast if you only intend to pass in the corresponding types.